# using Composition in c# android activity to access the data

Tags: c#, android, list, android-activity, xamarin

I'm developing an android application and using the IDE Xamarin studio. I have two activity classes, in the first activity class some function is carried out and returns the values. These values should be accessed in the other class (I mean the second activity class). I just normally created an instance of the first activity class in the second activity class and tried to access the values. But i think it was an error, as Xamarin Studio didn't show the variable name in the autocomplete list.

First Activity class:

```
public class getInformation : Activity
    {
        public string SourceText, DestText;
        public string[] source, destination;
        public int numval;

        public getInformation() { }

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.getInformation_activity);

            /* some fields and buttons go here

             */

            Button.Click += delegate{ //some extra code goes here...
                StartActivity(typeof(DisplayInformation));

                source = SourceText.Split(new String[]{','});
                destination = DestText.Split(new String[]{','});

                numval = Convert.ToInt32(source[0]);
            };

        }           
    }
```

Here, I'm trying to access the variables String[] source and int numval.

Second activity goes here:

```
public class DisplayInformation : Activity
    {
        public getInformation getaddress = new getInformation (); 
                                                    //instance of first class created.

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.displayInformation_Activity);

             //button click event not necessary mentioning here.
        }
       getaddress.numval;
                   // here it shows error, i mean it doesn't show numval in autocomplete.
    }
```

Now, my question is I want to access the values source[0], source[1] and numval by creating an instance to the first class in the second class (activity). Is there any way to access the data.

If there are any mistakes within my code please forgive me and correct my answer.

Comment: question solved - thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating SecondActivity from FirstActivity it is better to Set the information from the FirstActivity in SecondActivity than vice versa.

That way you ensure that both activities are actually still around when SecondActivity comes round to try and retrieve the data from FirstActivity.

There's (at least) two ways of doing this.

Option 1
Store the data inside of an intent and use that intent to start the SecondActvity.
http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/

Option 2

```
var secondActivity = StartActivity(typeof(SecondActivity));
secondActivity.SetMyData(data);
```

Comment: thank you it works. Previously, I defined the variables as static (to the global variables), which is big mistake. But your solution looks perfect.